# Poi ' characted seem to be added automatically

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use POI 3.1 to generate a xlsx file.

This character ' is added automcally in my cell

```
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(atm.getEnvelop());

   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
   cell.setCellValue(atm.getAmount().replace(".", ","));
```

atm.getEnvelop() and atm.getAmount() are string

atm.getEnvelop() value is 8635 but when i check in the file generated i get:' 8635

same thing for the other one

value is 200,00 i get '200,00

any idea?

Comment: Is there just an open single quote? No closing quote?

Comment: Excel ususally uses a single `'` to represent a cell that should be represented as text.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that you're calling `cell.setCellValue(String)`, which automatically sets the cell type to be a string

If you want to set a numeric cell type (so there's no `'` prefixed in Excel), you need to give Apache POI a number not a string.

This code will set `'200.00` in Excel:

```
String s200 = "200.00";
cell.setCellValue(s200);
```

While this one will give you `200.00` in Excel:

```
// Once per workbook - tell excel to format with with two decimal points
DataFormat fmt = wb.createDataFormat()
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
cs.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("0.00"));

// Once per cell
double d200 = 200.0;
cell.setCellValue(d200);
cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

For your case, where your number seems to be coming in as a String, you'll need to parser it into a number (eg double) before giving it to POI

Comment: The problem with this approach is that accuracy is lost for example, 143.40 becomes 143.399993896484375

Comment: @EliutIslas I'd suggest you go read up on floating point numbers, computers don't store things the way you apparently think they do!

Comment: I know, but the problem is Java POI and data type for real numbers, not Excel. If you create handly an Excel book with the value 143.40 it is preserved as is and not lose accuracy

Answer (score 1):

AT the place of cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
Use cell.setCellType(CELL_TYPE_STRING);

Because putting char '' is excel property for numeric value.

it could help you.

Comment: It makes sense, I expected it to work, but the apostrophe(') still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I am guessing you are trying to get an integer from a cell of Cell.Cell_TYPE_STRING. Try to get the amount from cell by calling this : cell.getNumericCellValue()